# Deserialize Json array in .NET7 project gives error

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I'm feeling stupid, because I get an error and cannot figure out why.

Error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Helpspot.CL.Model.Event]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |

Test class:

```
class Event {
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Test code:

```
var json = @"{""event"":[{""Year"":1945},{""Year"":1527}]}";
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Event>>(json);
```

It does work when I deserialize one object:

```
var json = @"{""Year"":1945}";
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(json);
```

Comment: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Event>>(json);

Comment: Why are you wrapping in another layer?

Comment: @DanielA.White Which layer?

Comment: @GHDevOps What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following JSON:

```
var json = @"{""event"":[{""Year"":1945},{""Year"":1527}]}";
```

Represents a JSON object with property `event` containing a collection of events, so either  fix the JSON (`var json = @"[{""Year"":1945},{""Year"":1527}]";`)
or add another type to represent your JSON correctly (another option would by "dynamic" deserialization with the [JSON DOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom)s):

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);

class Root {
    [JsonPropertyName("event")]
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have list of events.

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "year": 1945
        },
        {
            "year": 1945
        }
    ]
}


public partial class Events
{
    [JsonProperty("events")]
    public virtual List<Event> eventList { get; set; }
}

public partial class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public virtual long Year { get; set; }
}
```